# Python-How to run distinct sql queries in parallel

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a code that runs several sql queries in a loop.  Everything runs correctly, but the query is slow.  I was curious if anyone had thoughts on how I could accomplish the same goal in a quicker method or if there was a way to parallelize what I have to gain efficiencies.

```
#initialize DataFrames
df=pd.DataFrame([])
df2=pd.DataFrame([])
df3=pd.DataFrame([])

for i in range (0,len(hosts)):
    config={"all the configs"}
    cnx=mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    
    df=df.append(pd.read_sql(qry1))
    df2=df2.append(pd.read_sql(qry2))
    df3=df3.append(pd.read_sql(qry3))
```

Comment: Have you considered pooling ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

Comment: @gosalia Im working on that option now.  The url that you sent me to helps me get the shell of the syntax set up, but I am not seeing any examples where there are mlutiple sql queries used in pooling

Comment: @gosalia  here is what I tried for reference.  I have it working, but still seems slow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65117339/new-to-connection-pooling

Comment: can you specify and tell us more about your query and exactly what you are trying?

Comment: @gosalia I am trying to loop over 4 hosts to gather data from 7 different sql queries and then place the results in 7 distinct dataframes.  I have the query to do that, but I was hoping the time it take to gather the results could be optimized via connection pooling or multithreading.  I am using a mysql connector.

Comment: @gosalia so it'd look like this:  In Host 1 run (Query1, Query 2, etc..) and save results to a dataframe for each separate query (df1, df2, etc....) After this is done loop to Host2 and do the same queries (Query1, Query2, etc...) but append the results from the second loop to each dataframe.  So essentially you are left with 1 dataframe for each query with all the loops results.  Hope that makes sense.