# New to Connection Pooling

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, connection-pooling

So I am new to connection pooling.  I am trying to determine how to use a pool in order to speed up my query.  I have a query that works, but I dont think I am using the pool correct.  Here is the syntax, if you see anywhere I could be more efficient please let me know.

```
try:
    db=mysql.connector.connect(poolname="mypool", pool_size=10, **config)
    
    cursor.execute(query1)
    df1=create_df(cursor)
    
    cursor.execute(query2)
    df2=create_df(cursor)
    
    cursor.execute(query3)
    df3=create_df(cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question didn't make it clear how `cursor` comes from `db`.

Consider using [sqlalchemy](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sqlalchemy).
Then you get automatic pooling for free.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(your_local_mysql_url_with_credentials)
with engine.connect() as con:
    df1 = pd.read_sql(query1, con)
    df2 = pd.read_sql(query2, con)
    df3 = pd.read_sql(query3, con)
```

The pool winds up being an attribute of `engine`.
In practice you'll seldom care about inspecting it,
since it Just Works, hanging onto a server TCP connection across queries.

Comment: So I added what you said.  Do I need to explicitly say the pool size or do I need to explicitly state pool_size=10 in the create_engine statement?